# Java compiler and its cmd output

Tags: java, cmd

I cannot send output of JAVAC command in command prompt to a file with `javac >f.txt & f.txt` command. It creates only a  0byte file.

Comment: you're using unix? then javac ... 2> out.txt should do it

Comment: No i am using windows

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `javac` writes compilation error messages to standard error rather than standard output.  Try this:

```
  $ javac 2>f.txt YourClass.java
```